What are the legal consequences of publishing in massacre denial or hate speech according to paragraph 130 (5)?
Let's say a publication, especially a German publication, makes about five or six articles, denying for example a certain massacre, like let's say the Armenian massacre?
What are the legal consequences for that?

germany
The German Parliament has decided that the massacre on the Armenians shall be named a genocide.
Genocide denial is a crime according to §130 Abs 5 STGB. The act is illegal when performed in public and is intended or at least suitable to incite hatred or violence. Attempting to distribute a booklet is usually done in public. The penalty is prison of up to three years or a fine.

Yes but  I meant for the publication.

It not just has to be public, it has to be in a manner suitable to incite hatred or violence.

@o.m. True, overlooked that part. Updated the answer. That article has way to many conditions....

@Questioner I guess if the publication fulfils the criteria of §130 Abs 5 (which would need to be decided by a judge) its distribution will be prohibited and anybody trying to do so would risk a penalty.

@PMF, since the article clarifies when speech is not free, it had better have conditions. And the German tradition is to try to write them into the law, not the judicial precedent afterwards.

Volksverhetzung.
Denial of the Holocaust and similar atrocities falls under Volksverhetzung, § 130  StGB:

Whosoever, in a manner capable of disturbing the public peace:

incites hatred against a national, racial, religious group or a group defined by their ethnic origins, against segments of the population or individuals because of their belonging to one of the aforementioned groups or segments of the population or calls for violent or arbitrary measures against them; or
assaults the human dignity of others by insulting, maliciously maligning an aforementioned group, segments of the population or individuals because of their belonging to one of the aforementioned groups or segments of the population, or defaming segments of the population,

shall be liable to imprisonment from three months to five years.

As such, the prescribed punishment is incarceration for 3 months to 5 years. Monetary sanctions instead of imprisonment are not prescribed or allowed.
In the case of a magazine, the main offender is the writer of the article. He is fully liable. The magazine's chief editor (verantwortlicher Redakteur) and publisher can be liable as an associate or inciter.  (source)
Since no fines are allowed as punishment, fines are not allowed to be given.
For the company
Repeatedly publishing material that is volksverhetzend, violates Art. 1 GG (Human dignity shall be inviolable. To respect and protect it shall be the duty of all state authority.) could lead to a ban and dissolution of the magazine's operating company, a ban to publish it and more.
Individual people's compensation
If a magazine publishes material that is against a single individual, that one might sue for restitution under §§ 186, 187 StGB (Defamation) and § 823 BGB. This however wouldn't be applicable for things targeting a broad mass, such as antisemitic or holocaust denial material.
Declaration as propaganda and ban of the magazine and any follow-up.
In an extreme case, the magazine's publisher organization could be branded an illegal or terrorist organization, joining the NSDAP, PKK, and RAF (Rote Armee Fraktion). As a result, the magazine would immediately fall under §86 StGB: distribution of propaganda of unconstitutional or terrorist organizations - including all old material. Distributing or making any (new or old) copy of the magazine would then be illegal. For the example organizations above, this would be (among others) "Völkischer Beobachter" and "Der Stürmer" as magazines of the NSDAP, "Serxwebûn" as the publication of the PKK, and "Das Konzept Stadtguerilla" as a publication of the RAF.
Example case: COMPACT
The magazine COMPACT was (temporarily) banned on 16th July 2024 but was allowed to publish again one month later, as the ban was preliminary and partially revoked for the pendency of the trial only. [Actual court publication] The trial is scheduled for February. However, the BVerwG has indivated, in that court publication that there might be very good chances for the magazine ban to stand, if the single open question can be solved in trial:

Ob diese Vereinigung [COMPACT-Magazin GmbH] aber den - wie alle Gründe des § 3 Abs. 1 Satz 1 VereinsG, Art. 9 Abs. 2 GG eng auszulegenden - Verbotsgrund des Sichrichtens gegen die verfassungsmäßige Ordnung erfüllt, kann derzeit nicht abschließend beurteilt werden.


Whether this association [COMPACT-Magazin GmbH] fulfills the prohibition of acting against the constitutional order - like all reasons in Section 3 Paragraph 1 Sentence 1 of the Association Act, Article 9 Paragraph 2 of the Basic Law, which must be interpreted narrowly - cannot currently be conclusively assessed become.


What would be the consequences of that?

@Questioner Ask the investigating Staatsanwaltschaft or wait for February, when the court will rule on the issue if the magazine is, as an institution, banned.

Can I just email them or will my mails be just ignored

@Questioner The most likely answer from the Bundesstaatsanwaltschaft or any Staatsanwaltschaft in one of the states will be "No Comment" because this is a running case - and as such they are barred from commenting. The party sued by Compact is the BMI, who have a press delegate, and who also would most likely answer "no comment".

@Questioner and atop that: the offices are mostly closed till new years, only emergency stuff will be handled. The best chance is to wait till february and sit in on the trial.
